# Is there a faster way than bfs to get the shortest path length in a 2d grid

Tags: multidimensional-array, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, shortest-path

I had this question in an assessment where I was given parameters of a max path length and a 2d grid of characters where 'o' = space you can travel on and 'x' = obstacle where you cant.

The goal of the problem was to return true if I could go from the top left corner of the grid to the bottom right if the path length is < the max path length parameter. If it's greater than or not possible at all, return false. You can move L, R, U, or D as long as you do not move to a 'x'. The top left corner is always 'o'.

My code was a standard bfs to check if its possible to travel to the bottom right corner and if is is, return the path length. However, the code was not fast enough for some of the test cases. Am I missing something? Is there a quicker way to check if a path exists between the two points on the grid less than a particular max path value?

my bfs

- kept track of the path length of each point
- kept track of visited states

Comment: You might be more interested in A* and its various derivative pathfinding algorithms. BFS will always find the shortest path, but it's far from the fastest algorithm to do it.

Comment: @Rogue Isn't A* only for weighted graphs? This is unweighted

Comment: You can use A* on an unweighted graph by pretending every edge has weight 1.

Comment: Possibly overkill, but might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_point_search